# SoftKeyboard moves my TextViews out of display

Tags: android, screen, android-softkeyboard

I know this question was asked properly before, but all answers i found didnt work for me. so heres my issue:

when i call my players activity (to enter playernames) it looks like this:

[image]

but when i click on `01. Player` this happens:

[image]

and i am not able to scroll up.

I want the display to keep the first players on screen, and not moving the players 1 to 3 out of screen.

Heres my XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player02"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player03"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player04"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player05"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player05"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player06"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player06"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player07"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player07"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player08"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player08"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player09"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player09"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player10"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player11"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player12"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player13"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player14"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player15"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player15"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/TV_player16"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_player16"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/CONT_laynameinputbottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_nameinput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CONT_ni_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTN_ni_exit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTN_ni_next"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTN_ni_clearall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

please help

EDIT: I add my Manifest, too.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="bowltec.control"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"
    tools:ignore="OldTargetApi" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.MainFrame"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.GameSettings"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.ConfirmChosen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.NameInput"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.GameList"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.Correction"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.Menu"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.Language"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name="bowltec.control.AddLang"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
</application>
```

Comment: first check in your menifest whether there is property set as android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation", if so then please omit this property.

Comment: @Maneesh either i am not able to implement that correctly or it doesnt work ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the windowSoftInputMode in your AndroidManifest.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
```

Lars Vogel posted a nice little piece on this feature on his [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/). And there is more on the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Comment: Did you fiddle with all the options? adjustPan and adjustResize

Comment: tried (i think) all of them standalone and in combination, but nothing changes